# How to install mdenoise on linux?

Tags: linux, hillshade

It is suggested to [install mdenoise](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass-addons/grass6/raster/r.denoise/description.html#L4) via :

```
wget http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/meshfiltering/index_files/Doc/mdsource.zip
unzip mdsource.zip
cd mdenoise
g++ -o mdenoise mdenoise.cpp triangle.c
ln -s `pwd`/mdenoise /some/directory/on/the/$PATH
```

But it fails, returning :

```
g++ -o ./script/mdenoise/mdenoise ./script/mdenoise/mdenoise.cpp 
./script/mdenoise/triangle.c
./script/mdenoise/mdenoise.cpp: In function ‘void ReadXYZ(FILE*)’:
./script/mdenoise/mdenoise.cpp:1418:44: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings] 
         triangulate("zqBQ",&in,&out,&vorout);
                                            ^
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529194/ , with solution in [How to get rid of `deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’` warnings in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59687/1974961)
, aka, it need to pass `-Wno-write-strings` to `g++`:

**Install mdenoise on linux:**

```
mkdir -p ./scripts
curl -L -C - 'http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/meshfiltering/index_files/Doc/mdsource.zip' -o './scripts/mdsource.zip'
unzip -n ./scripts/mdsource.zip -d ./scripts/
g++ -Wno-write-strings -o ./scripts/mdenoise/mdenoise ./scripts/mdenoise/mdenoise.cpp ./scripts/mdenoise/triangle.c
# ln -s `pwd`/mdenoise /some/directory/on/the/$PATH
```